# FilrerDeep using deepdash keeping rollup verdict

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, lodash

I would like to use filterDeep from [deepdash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepdash)(any other solution is also fine) to filter my data below so that the rollup of verdict is kept intact.

```
{
"diff": [
    {
        "actual": "parent1",
        "expected": "parent1",
        "match": true,
        "children": [
            {
                "actual": "child1",
                "expected": "child1",
                "match": true,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "actual": "grandchild1",
                        "expected": "grandchild1_NOT",
                        "match": true
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "actual": "child2",
                "expected": "child2",
                "match": true,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "actual": "C2_grandchild1",
                        "expected": "C2_grandchild1",
                        "match": true
                    },
                    {
                        "actual": "C2_grandchild2",
                        "expected": "C2_grandchild2_NOT",
                        "match": false
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

The simple view of the json is like:

[image]

I would like to filter out in such a way that since **C2_grandchild2** is failed(match:false), the json should contain parent1--> child2-->C2grandchild2. I am trying to highlight the fails with also showing its parent hierarchy. So child1, grandchild1 and C2_grandchild1 is also not present in the filtered json

I have tried the example [here](https://deepdash.io/#filterdeep) but can't seem to understand it quite well to be able to achieve this

PS: the json most of the times is quite big and deep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a recursive function, which maps an array of nodes to a filtered array based on the following principle:

- if the node has children, and the recursive call returns a non-empty array, then add a new node to the result that has this reduced array of children
- if the node has no children, or the recursive call returns an empty array, then:

  - if the node has `match: false`, add this node as-is to the result
  - otherwise, do not add this node to the result
- Return the resulting array

```js
function filter(nodes) {
    return (nodes || []).map(node => {
        let { children, ...childlessNode} = node;
        children = filter(children);
        return children.length ? {...node, children } 
                               : !node.match && childlessNode;
    }).filter(Boolean);
}

// Demo
let data = {"diff": [{"actual": "parent1","expected": "parent1","match": true,"children": [{"actual": "child1","expected": "child1","match": true,"children": [{"actual": "grandchild1","expected": "grandchild1_NOT","match": true}]},{"actual": "child2","expected": "child2","match": true,"children": [{"actual": "C2_grandchild1","expected": "C2_grandchild1","match": true},{"actual": "C2_grandchild2","expected": "C2_grandchild2_NOT","match": false}]}]}]};
let result = { diff: filter(data.diff) };
console.log(result);
```

This snippet outputs the same `diff` property. If you don't need that upper level, then just call `filter(data.diff)` without wrapping that result in another object.

### Explanations

`(nodes || [])` evaluates to `nodes`, except when `nodes` is not an array, but undefined. This may happen when the function is called with `node.children`, but `node` does have a `children` property. JavaScript allows to reference properties that do not exist, and it will just evaluate such a reference to the special value `undefined`. So if this function receives `undefined` as argument, it will continue the expression with an empty array `[]`. Otherwise the `.map` call would trigger an exception.

`.map` will produce a new array with just as many elements as the array on which it is called. The callback function that is provided as argument will define the value that the new array gets for a given value in the original array ("mapping").

`{ children, ...childlessNode} = node;` will get the `children` property of `node` in a `children` variable (or `undefined` when `node` does not have such a property), but more importantly, it will also create an object variable `childlessNode` having all *other* properties of `node`.

`filter(children)`: this is the recursive call. As stated above, it might be that `node` does not have a `children` property, but that is treated well by the `filter` function. It will always return an array.

`children.length ? ...... : .....`: a ternary operator is used to distinguish the case where the recursive function returned a non-empty array, or it returned an empty one.

`{...node, children }`: this is a compact syntax for saying: create a new object that is a (shallow) copy of `node`, but whose `children` property should be set to the `children` variable. Note that `...` is the [spread syntax for object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals).

`!node.match && childlessNode`: if `node.match` is true, then `!node.match` is false, and the `&&` operator short-circuits making the expression `false`. This actually means that the array created in this `.map` call can contain `false` values, as well as nodes. Note that JavaScript allows this mix of types. If `!node.match` is false, then the expression evaluates to `childlessNode`, meaning that the mapping of this `node` is just the node itself, but without children.

`.filter(Boolean)`: this will create yet another array from the array that `.map` returned. This time the number of values in the new array can be smaller. The callback function provided as argument will determine which values should be in, and which should be out. `Boolean` is a native function that can be used for this purpose. `Boolean(false)` is just `false`, while `Boolean(any object)` is `true`. So this effectively returns an array where the `false` values are removed from, only keeping the node objects.

Comment: Thanks. I works good. Since I come from core java world more. I need to do more complex kind of fitering, it would be good if you could explain a little more if that okay or  I'll try running a number of times and find out. But Thanks a lot

Comment: I added some explanations.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry to come back again on this. Little more help. If I make the "Child1"'s match: false, then it should remove the grandchild1 and should show only parent->child1, it should not show the grandchild1 since that has "match:true"

Answer (score 1):

with deepdash you will have something like this:

```js
// data is your json
const failed = _.filterDeep(data.diff,(v) => !v.match, {
  childrenPath:'children'
});
```

[Here is a working example](https://codepen.io/yurigor/pen/BaKxyZO?editors=0010)

`(v) => !v.match` -- this is filtering criteria

`{ childrenPath:'children' }` -- option to declare children property name, to make deepdash work in 'tree mode'

lmk if any questions

Comment: Thanks, works great. Will be useful for later use. I have used the answer by @trincot